# Choosing a default class as 'active' to open an iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have this piece of code to open a different iframe each time a user clicks on a button. However i noticed that, when someone loads the page, there isn't any "default" iframe to open so the iframe looks black and empty. Is there a way i can edit the code to let a class be active by default?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Catch all clicks on a link with the class 'link'
  $('.link').click(function(e) {

  // Stop the link being followed:
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get the div to be shown:
  var content = $(this).attr('rel');

  // Remove any active classes:
  $('.active').removeClass('active');

  // Add the 'active' class to this link:
  $(this).addClass('active');

  // Hide all the content:
  $('.content').hide();

  // Show the requested content:
  $('#' + content).show();
});
```

Comment: Need HTML and CSS in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.net) or snippet (Use the 7th icon on the comment toolbar.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, it tries to show your first link on page load.  I can't test because I don't have all your code but hopefully this is close to what you were looking for.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    showLink($('.link').first());

    // Catch all clicks on a link with the class 'link'
    $('.link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showLink($(this));    
    });

    function showLink(ele){

          // Get the div to be shown:
          var content = ele.attr('rel');

          // Remove any active classes:
          $('.active').removeClass('active');

          // Add the 'active' class to this link:
          ele.addClass('active');

          // Hide all the content:
          $('.content').hide();

          // Show the requested content:
          $('#' + content).show();
    }
});
```